# Cocoa Touch Framework - Parent App communication

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I am building a cocoa touch framework to provide users with services like Login with my app. This framework will be used by all third party apps and use service like Login (Yes indeed like Facebook Framework)

**Project overview:**

1. An application (Let's call 'Parent App') written using swift, offers service like Login.
2. A cocoa touch framework written using swift, invokes parent app to use Login service.

> Only requirement is when my parent app logout all the third party app (integrated framework) using login service should logout.

**Options:**

- Option 1: How can I trigger notification from parent app to all third party apps that integrated the framework?
- Option 2: How can I share data (Login Status) between my parent app to framework, so when the third party app is launched, I can read the data stored in it?

PS: As I cannot specify the Entitlements to framework and third party apps(which will be developed by some other developer), I believe I cannot share keychain / user defaults. And URL schema cannot be used to share the data as it launches the third party apps.

Do you think I have any other options to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per iOS 8.3 we dont have any thing to handle this. Unless user experience is compromised by URL Schema method.

May be in future... iOS 9?